# Limit date range selection on Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I copied a datepicker bootstrap online but I want to set a limit on how many days the user can select in the calendar, like you can only select maximum of 7 days ie: Jan 1, 2016 - Jan 7, 2016 = OK
Jan 12, 2016 - Jan 15, 2016 = OK
Jan 19, 2016 - Jan 29, 2016 = ERROR

Comment: There are many Datepicker Bootstrap available over the web, could you specify exactly which one you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

.. here is bootstrap datepicker available which can solve your issue. You can refer this link: http://www.daterangepicker.com/
or use this in your script:

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 1:30 PM - 01/01/2015 2:00 PM" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 30,
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I am using this one because I also need the calendar view of to see the current events registered. I cant find the ID of the datepicker so I cant create a script for the date range limiter https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=kitchen-sink

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI DatePicker, It has a **minDate** property you can set to suppress the user from selecting older than that day.